# Troubleshooting Errors with Two SUMs

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, erp

[image]

I have a table, it's going to be used for a supplier scorecard, with eleven different fields that can be assigned a value of 1-5. Null values are allowed.

I need to write a query that will calculate the average of the fields that are filled out by each row. In other words, I might be dividing TOTAL by 11 in one row, and dividing TOTAL by 5 in another.

I'm working with this query:

```
select 
cf$_vendor_no, 
cf$_party,  
cf$_environmental, 
cf$_inspections, 
cf$_invoice_process, 
cf$_ncr, 
cf$_on_time_delivery, 
cf$_qms, 
cf$_safety, 
cf$_schedule, 
cf$_scope_of_work, 
cf$_turn_times,
sum(nvl(cf$_environmental,0)
+nvl(cf$_inspections,0)
+nvl(cf$_invoice_process,0)
+nvl(cf$_ncr,0)
+nvl(cf$_on_time_delivery,0)
+nvl(cf$_qms,0)
+nvl(cf$_safety,0)
+nvl(cf$_schedule,0)
+nvl(cf$_scope_of_work,0)
+nvl(cf$_turn_times,0)) 
/
sum(
case when cf$_environmental is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when cf$_inspections is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when cf$_invoice_process is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when cf$_ncr is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when cf$_on_time_delivery is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when cf$_qms is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when cf$_safety is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when cf$_schedule is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when cf$_scope_of_work is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when cf$_turn_times is not null then 1 else 0 end) --as "average"
from supplier_scorecard_clv  
group by cf$_vendor_no, cf$_party, cf$_environmental, cf$_inspections, cf$_invoice_process, cf$_ncr, cf$_on_time_delivery, cf$_qms, cf$_safety, cf$_schedule, cf$_scope_of_work, cf$_turn_times
```

And, it almost works.

The first SUM in my code will add the values in each row to give me a total. I get a total 25 for the first FARW002 row, I get 6 for the second, and 12 for the third.

The second SUM in my code works as well. I get a count of 6 for my first FARW002 row, 2 for my second, and 3 for my third.

However, when I try to combine these, like in the code snippet above, I get a "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What is your desire output? And why are you using `GROUP BY` ? doesn't seem necessary on this case.

Comment: Hi Juan, I mentioned what the desired output is about "I need to write a query that will calculate the average of the fields that are filled out by each row. In other words, I might be dividing TOTAL by 11 in one row, and dividing TOTAL by 5 in another."

The error comes up regardless of whether group by is in place or not. I didn't ask about the group by. I'm asking about ORA-00923.

Comment: You can interpret those words in different ways. Show me the output the same as you show in the picture the current data. As I interpret those words you dont even need `GROUP BY` that is why I need you be specific to make sure I understand the problem the right way

Comment: Again, "I need to write a query that will calculate the average of the fields that are filled out by each row. In other words, I might be dividing TOTAL by 11 in one row, and dividing TOTAL by 5 in another."

Row 1 has 6 values, Row 2 has 2, and Row 3 has 3. So, if we're "calculat[ing] the average of the fields that are filled out by each row," we would be dividing 25 by 6 for the first row, 6 by 2 in the second, and 12 by 3 in the third.

Comment: Please try to add the expected output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, this is stupid but here's what the problem ended up being:

```
 +nvl(cf$_turn_times,0))  
/ 
sum(
```

When I changed the code to this - really I was just dicking around - it worked:

```
+nvl(cf$_turn_times,0))/sum(
```

So, something about having the / and SUM separated from the rest of the query - which I only do to make the code more readable for me - was causing the issue.
Thanks for nothing Juan!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: This is probably due to a line that consists of a slash having a special meaning in Oracle's sql*plus. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm